# Grid overlay in Bootstrap pannel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit trouble when inserting a grid inside the body of a panel. I've tried this so far and still can't get it working.

---

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

EDIT WITH ANSWER:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>
                       Panel test</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                    </i></cite></small>
                    <p>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>email@example.com
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>June 02, 1988</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: looks ok to me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxrNWE browser?

Comment: @stig-js Looks OK to me also there, but not on my project. I'm using Chrome. It's a scope inside an AngularJS implementation, but it should work. It looks okey on small screens.

Comment: yes it works in my browser also

Comment: all though you can try img-responsive make image responsive

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers Thanks! That and a small change in the grid made the magic. Edited with the answer :)